# Surrounding 2 inner boxes with one outer box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve what is on the attached desired.png (specifically so that the other box surrounds the 2 inner boxes).

[image]

I use the following code but there is no outer box surrounding the 2 inner boxes. How can I achieve what is on the image?

Sandbox

```
            <style type="text/css">
            #wrap {
               //width:600px;
               //margin:0 auto;
               border:1px solid red;
               //height:100px;
            }
            #left_col {
               float:left;
               width:300px;
               border:1px solid black;
            }
            #right_col {
               float:right;
               width:300px;
               border:1px solid orange;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="wrap">
        <span id="left_col">
            ...
        </span>
        <span id="right_col">
            ...
        </span>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Css does not have the // Comment format. You only can use /* */. This will be one error. You have to set the height of the containing container, too. Because floating elements do not apply to the height of the outer container. And do not miss the height of the inner container. My modified css would be:

```
#wrap {

border:1px solid red;
height: 100px;
width: 600px;
padding: 5px;
}
#left_col {
float:left; 
display: inline-block;
width:295px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
#right_col {
float:right; 
display: inline-block;
width:295px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest *fix* would be to float #wrap. This will mean it will fully wrap around the floated elements within it and expand to accomodate their height.

You may find that this is impractical in your layout in which case a clearfix method will do the trick. There are a number of ways to do this as have already been shown.

Personally, if semantically applicable, I might use an hr element with clear:both applied to it via a css class.

```
.clearer {
    clear:both; 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

But each to their own. Nowadays it's safe to use content:after

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left_col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="right_col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>​
```

Css

```
 #wrap {
           width:610px;

           border:1px solid red;
          padding:5px;
        }
        #left_col {
           float:left;
           width:300px;
           border:1px solid black;
        }
        #right_col {
           float:right;
           width:300px;
           border:1px solid orange;
        }​
```

Comment: I would recommend using [.clearfix](http://j.mp/bestclearfix) instead of this hack.

Answer (score 0):

Floats wrap the initial height of an object to it's content.
If there is no content in the inner divs, you won't see anything but the borders.

I would also recommend having a look at [.clearfix](http://j.mp/bestclearfix) because floating things within the `#wrap` without "fixing the floats" means that `#wrap` won't pick up their heights in turn.

---

To answer your question:

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:604px
}
.col {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

/* The Amazing clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
    <span class="col">
        Content!
    </span>
    <span class="col">
        Content!
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo, adjust the width and height as per your spec,

[My Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/uwr6e/1/)

HTML:
    --------

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left_col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="right_col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>​

CSS:
------

#wrap {
    width:420px;
    border:2px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#left_col { 
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid #FFA9C5;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#right_col {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#wrap`

```
#wrap {
               //width:600px;
               //margin:0 auto;
               border:1px solid red;
               //height:100px; overflow:auto
            }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SowmyaShivaram/Fwjd4/22/)**